# Split an angular string inside ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

I know there are other questions about this, but I already tryed and nothing seems to work.

I basically have an angular variable retrieved from an $http.get .
The content is html encoded, like:

```
Paperwhite &#8211; Human Nature
```

So I have to display it as

```
<div ng-bind-html="songrel.title.rendered"></div>
```

To render the html:

> Paperwhite – Human Nature

I want to split this value for the `-` and display only

> Human Nature

I tryed something like

```
<div ng-bind-html="songrel.title.rendered.split('&#8211;')[1]"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-bind-html="songrel.title.rendered.split('-')[1]"></div>
```

Or moving the code in my app.config

```
$scope.showFirstBr = function(content){
    return content.split('&#8211;')[1]
};
```

and then

```
<div ng-bind-html="showFirstBr(songrel.title.rendered)"></div>
```

but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed adding this in the controller:

```
$scope.showFirstBr = function(content){
    var c = content.replace('&#8211;','-');
    return c.split('-')[1]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $sce) {
  var str = 'Paperwhite &#8211; Human Nature';
  $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml(str.split('&#8211;')[1]);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="test"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've fix with this  `$scope.showFirstBr = function(content){
  var c = content.replace('&#8211;','-');
  return c.split('-')[1]
 };` as an user wrote (he deleted the answer). My variable is the result of an $http.get that returns one or mutiple array. I have to access it inside an ng-repeat. Not sure how to use your code